# I try to build hexagon from this code but when I run it. It not appear

Tags: html, css

I have try to build hexagon from this code but when I run it. It not nothing happen on my screen I have try another code too. But it still nothing happen. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hex.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is HTML code.

```
.main {
    display:flex;
    --s: 100px;  /* size  */
    --m: 4px;    /* margin */
    --f: calc(var(--s) * 1.732 + 4 * var(--m) - 1px); 
  }
  
  .container {
    font-size: 0; /* disable white space between inline block element */
  }
  
  .container div {
    width: var(--s);
    margin: var(--m);
    height: calc(var(--s) * 1.1547);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:initial;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 0% 75%, 50% 100%, 100% 75%, 100% 25%, 50% 0%);
    margin-bottom: calc(var(--m) - var(--s) * 0.2885);
  }
  
  .container::before {
    content: "";
    width: calc(var(--s) / 2 + var(--m));
    float: left;
    height: 120%; 
    shape-outside: repeating-linear-gradient(#0000 0 calc(var(--f) - 3px), #000 0 var(--f));
  }
```

Here is CSS code

What's wrong on this code or I have to download extension on vscode before run this?

Comment: There is nothing in your code to generate a hexagon.

Comment: I add wrong code so sorry.